# How do I change PATH for pip?

Tags: terminal, python, path, macos, pip

I have different versions of python on my macos mojave and i could get the right path for python editing the -bash_profile, but can't get the same for pip Path.

pip3 is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pip3
pip and pip3 are alias

That's where it is now and I need to put in the same directory of the python 3.7, the one im using with anaconda3. I tried editing the -bash_profile and the -bashrc, but neither of them worked. I restarted terminal and saved the changes, but still i get the same. I would really appreciate if someone could help me

Comment: Add the contents of `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` to your question.